# Anti phishing software?

Tags: security, browser, search

Is there an anti phishing software in ubuntu which may even rate websites while searching and surfing ,something like avg secure search in windows or the software u get with bitdefender which puts a ticks or crosses on links while searching.Though most modern browsers come with minimal anti phishing settings(or tools) but a good independent software working on all browsers(I am talking about even the not so famous ones) and rating websites wood be good.

Comment: There *are* extensions for both Firefox and Chrome that do that.

Comment: Extensions in that case are more trustworthy , just personal thought .

Comment: could using a good hosts file be a possible remedy? besides what about website ratings

Comment: there is an rating app called WOT which is available on opera,firefox and chrome stores there is also something called wotsap on ubuntu software center but I dont get if its the same thing or not?

Answer (score 5):

You can route your DNS through something like OpenDNS or Google Public DNS:

- http://www.opendns.com/business-solutions/premium-dns/benefits/

This is free and can easily be installed at router level to give network-wide protection.

Comment: i dont get the point 8 in configuring dns in this page -https://store.opendns.com/setup/operatingsystem/ubuntu   how to do it please help

Comment: No, I don't understand that point either. It suggests that the DNS settings in Network Manager are not permanent but that is contrary to my experience. I'd just carry on without point 8 and check http://welcome.opendns.com to make sure it's working. Or install it at router level and forget all about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install bitdefender or Avast.

Steps to install bitdefender:

```
cd /tmp
wget -O BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner.run http://download.bitdefender.com/SMB/Workstation_Security_and_Management/BitDefender_Antivirus_Scanner_for_Unices/Unix/Current/EN_FR_BR_RO/Linux/BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.6-4.linux-gcc4x.i586.deb.run
chmod +x BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner.run
sudo ./BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner.run
```

Once you install and run bitdefender program. It will monitor the sites for any security threat that you visit.

Comment: u r taking about antivirus or any other bitdefender product? do they protect from phishing too

Comment: Yes bitdefender provides warning regarding phishing sites.